# Android/ArduinoBT Connection

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect my Samsung Galaxy Tab to my ArduinoBT with bluetooth.

My code :

```
    public void run()
{
    if (adapter == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
    try {
        socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        socket.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When I launch the application, I've this window :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlc3x.png

I write the password : 0000

And in eclipse, I can see :

```
02-05 19:14:36.828: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(4952): connectNative
02-05 19:14:41.296: V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(4952): ...connect(52, RFCOMM) = 111 (errno 111)
02-05 19:14:41.296: W/System.err(4952): java.io.IOException: Connection refused
02-05 19:14:41.296: W/System.err(4952):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
02-05 19:14:41.296: W/System.err(4952):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:236)
02-05 19:14:41.296: W/System.err(4952):     at iut.robot.BluetoothThread.run(BluetoothThread.java:38)
```

I don't understand, when I used this application : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.dzs.android.BluetoothSPP&hl=fr
It's worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Your Bluetooth code looks fine.

Here are few suggestions that might resolve your problem:

- Pair your ArduinoBT, from Bluetooth Settings, before you launch the application.
- Make sure that there is only *one* app connected to your ArduinoBT (restart Bluetooth in your tablet to disconnect any current connections)
- Make sure that the Bluetooth Mac address is in correct format i.e. `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`
- Check that android app has the required permissions `android.permission.BLUETOOTH`, you can also add `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` but it is **not** required for your case

**Edit:**

If you correctly paired with the AurdionoBT and already entered the `pin` during the pairing process, you can try to connect with `insecure RFcomm`

```
socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
```

Comment: I've pair my ArduinoBT from bluetooth settings before. Only one app is connected on my Arduino. Bluetooth mac address is also OK. And permissions in AndroidManifest.xml are OK. If you want I can push application code online.